# Python Packaging: Ask user for variable values when (pip) installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-packaging

I have python package that at some point reads a file from `FPATH='path/to/file'`.
When installing the package with pip, I would like to ask for user input to define the value of `FPATH` and pass it to the installed package.
What would be the best way of doing so?
Unless I have missed something, `setuptools` does not seem to provide that option.

Comment: If you gonna to publish a wheel there is no executable code that `pip install` will run. With `pip install some.whl` pip installs the package declaratively (using prepared metadata). `setup.py` is being run at package time, not installation time.

Comment: Also consider that packages are often installed by building pipelines in CI and asking for user input will break that.