# Python Packaging: user specified file path

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am writing a python package which is dependent on a number of large data files. These files are *not* included with the package. Instead, users are required to have these files on disk already (with an arbitrary path). What is the best way to make my package aware of the location of these files?

I have been reading about `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` but I am still not sure how to to this. It seems to me that a user-editable option in `setup.cfg` would be a good way to go but I don't know if it is, if it can be done at all, or how I would do it if so...

I did see this almost identical question, [Python Packaging: Ask user for variable values when (pip) installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60238346/python-packaging-ask-user-for-variable-values-when-pip-installing), which focuses on user input during pip (which is discouraged in the comments). *If* that actually would be a good solution, I'm interested in how to do that too.

In my private development of the package, I have used module constants, as in

```
DEFAULT_PATH_FILE1 = "my/path/to/file1.csv"
DEFAULT_PATH_FILE2 = "my/path/to/file2.csv"
```

etc. and properties initialized with these constants. This doesn't seem viable at all for distribution.

Comment: important for context, does your package provide a command line interface?

Comment: No, that is not the intention. It (mainly) defines a class that facilitate data analysis across the different data files. The intended usage is to import and use this class at will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not a one-time setup during install (which is also impossible with modern `.whl` installs), but a way for clients to configure your library at any point during runtime. Given that you don't provide a cli, you can either use environment variables as an option to provide that , or look for a user-defined config file.

This here is a simple recipe using [`appdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/) to find out where the config file should be found. It loads on import of your package, and tells clients how bad it is if the config file isn't there. Usually, that'd be:

- write a log message
- use default settings
- throw some kind of exception
- a combination of the above

```py
from logging import getLogger
from pathlib import Path
from configparser import ConfigParser
# loads .ini format files easily, just to have an example to go with

import appdirs  # needs to be pip-installed

log = getLogger(__name__)
config = ConfigParser(interpolation=None)


# load config, substitute "my_package" with the actual name of your package
config_path = Path(appdirs.user_config_dir("my_package")) / "user.ini"
try:
    with open(config_path) as f:
        config.read_file(f, source="user")
except FileNotFoundError:
    # only do whatever makes sense
    log.info(f"User config expected at '{config_path}', but not found.")
    config.read_string("[pathes]\nfile_foo=foo\nfile_bar=bar")  # dubious
    raise ImportError(f"Can't use this module; create a config at '{config_path}'.")


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        with open(cfg["pathes"]["file_foo"]) as f:
            self.data = f.read()
```

Comment: That log event won't go anywhere unless the logging system has already been configured *before* importing the module.

Comment: True, [short](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/4f7a46775c90f83cffa2a0ac0c6cd27b), [longer](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html), and [longest](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) explanations on how to set up loggers, in case anyone is interested. The question is not about logging, so I'll leave it in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like runtime *configuration*. It's none of the business of `setup.py`, which is concerned with *installing* your package.

For app configuration, it would be common to specify this resource location by command-line argument, environment variable, or configuration file. You will usually want to either hard-code some sensible default path in case the user does not specify any configuration, or raise an exception in case of resources not existing / not found.

Example for environment var:

```
import os

DEFAULT_PATH_FILE1 = "/default/path/to/file1.csv"
PATH_FILE1 = os.environ.get("PATH_FILE1", DEFAULT_PATH_FILE1)
```

Comment: True, it is runtime configuration. The package will mainly be loaded as a module — is there still a way to have one-time command-line configuration command to specify the paths? A configuration file sounds appealing to me. How is that done?

Comment: You just load configuration from an file at `~/.config/myapp.conf` or wherever.  Document the default config file path and provide a way to override this location (e.g. another env var `MYAPP_CONF_FILE`). The existence of a config file at all should generally be _optional_.